# Text size issue in Preference screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing an application for launching a preference screen.
The first item is just a preference.
Second item is a preference with an icon on its right side.
In order to do the second item, what I did was calling a layout which has a textview and an image view.

```
     <Preference
    android:key="advanced_settings"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:layout="@layout/main"
```

and the main layout is:

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="Advanced settings" 
/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageview1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:src="@drawable/ic_bt_config"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But after the launch of application It is seen that text display is  text size is small and the space is not compatible with other space.
I dont want to hard code any thing.

Please help me how can I make the second item of the preference screen as same format that of the first item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

So that i will look like the text of the preference